# How to make android application check for a specific file in phone storage

Tags: android

Right so basically I would like to make a type of secure apk file which only starts up fully if the file is present in the phone storage, I will be providing these 'license' files privately to each individual person, the files doesn’t need to contain anything it’s just a noob way of stopping people from leaking my work when I do not wish to share it with the world.

I’ve been looking at the way apk's check for obb's but I see its far more complicated and i do not wish to follow this procedure.

hope somebody can help me

thank you

Answer (score 0):

So we need a list of files. We can get it like this:

```
String directoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(); // getInternalStorageDirectory for internal storage
File file = new File(directoryPath);        
File files[] = file.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    String name = file[i].getName();
}
```

And also for accessing external storage you need the following permission in Android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: so if i use this code, will the app not start if the file is not present ?

Comment: and can i add this code to main activity since i want it to run during application start up ?

Comment: If the file doesn't exist then I think you should just show a screen that you're forbidden to login. Otherwise you should let user to enter the app.